# Duplicate input same amount of times in new lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm in my first coding class and still getting the hang of it.

I need to write a code that will print a line of '+' a certain amount of times in the same line but also new lines at the same time depending on the number entered.

So far I only have the code to print '+' once each time in a new line:

```
def draw_a_line_of_plus(length):

 for i in range (length):
    print ('+', end='')
```

Comment: You can use the multiplication operator with strings in python.  I.e. `print('+'*length, end='')`.

Comment: About the `also new lines at the same time depending on the number entered` you should use `if-else` statement.